# Express render view and download file at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I would like to use express to render a file AND download a file at the same time

My current code is as follows:

```
res.attachment('filename.csv');
res.render('pages/result', { data });
```

However, if I do this, it only downloads the data and does not render the view

What I want is to render a success page, and then send the file so that it downloads

I need this to be done with 1 endpoint, because, I need to generate the file and only if it is successful, I would render the success page

Am I able to do this with 1 endpoint?

Thank you

Comment: How about  `res.download` instead of `res.attachment`?

Comment: The file is generated on the fly (csv), so I can't use download because I am not saving it, I am just sending csv as a file

Answer (score 0):

Don't think doing both is possible in 1 endpoint. What you can do is that, whenever you want to download the file place a js code to download the file inside the ejs template in a condition so that it is only downloaded whenever you want.

Comment: The issue I have with this, is that, I need to generate the file and make an api call, and only if it is successful, I would render the success page

Comment: the rendered page is in your control right, you can declare a js variable (using ejs templating) with path in script tag which you have wrapped inside condition of ejs

Answer (score 0):

send the path of the file to the render page as variable and write a function in javascript to download the file automatically.

```
res.render('pages/result', { path: '../folder/filename.csv'});
```

on render page

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = #{path};
};
</script>
```

[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)